# Why pair space but space=<number>mm in marker.asy?

Tags: asymptote

```
settings.outformat="pdf"; 
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import markers;

unitsize(1cm);
size(10cm,0);
defaultpen(linewidth(1bp));
//----------
marker pstslash=StickIntervalMarker(i=1,n=1,angle=-30,size=4mm,space=0);
marker pstslashh=StickIntervalMarker(i=1,n=2,angle=-30,size=4mm,space=1.75mm);
marker pstslashhh=StickIntervalMarker(i=1,n=3,angle=-30,size=4mm,space=1.75mm);
//------------
path p=(0,0)--(5,0);
transform T=shift((0,-1));
draw(p,marker=pstslash);
draw(T*p,marker=pstslashh);
draw(T^2*p,marker=pstslashhh);
dot(p^^T*p^^T^2*p,dotfactor*linewidth(3));
```

[image]

In marker.asy, I see

[image]

Question: Why?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Different functions can have different argument variables with different names that may or may not be related. Are you asking why particular arguments have the name that they have? Or how the arguments are related in functions/constructors that are called when you define a marker? Or what the purpose of a particular argument is? Do you have a practical problem that needs to be solved, or is it just out of general interest?

Comment: @Marijn I see `pair space`, so i think it should be `space=(x,y)`, however, as displayed, it is `space=<real>mm`. And my question, why or as you said: how the arguments are related in functions/constructors that are called when you define a marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Asymptote casts `real` to `pair`. See documentation: 6.13 **Casts**
and try for example `real a=1;` `pair g=a;` `write (g);`.

Comment: Yes, good. This my test: `path g=(0,0)--(2,0); pair space=2mm; real a=2mm; draw(g); draw(shift(space)*g);`.But, how to display your example?. I try but I don't see the output! Because I want to know the equivalent coordinate of `pair space=2mm;`:-)

Comment: size can be specified in `mm`, `bp`, `cm`, `inches`. `1mm` is converted in `1` multiplied by `2.834...`. In the case of the `marker` routine, using the deferred drawing `space=4mm` gives precisely a shifted 4mm space. `write` is equivalent to the `print` C function : print in the output message but not in the picture.